# Probability of Opening a Combination Lock

Tags: probability

A combination padlock has three rotating disks each with numbers 1 through 9. You forgot your code but remember that the sum of the three numbers is 8. In an attempt to open the lock, you begin entering all codes whose sum is 8. What is the probability that you will open the lock on the fourth try?

I am getting 1/21 but would like to confirm this answer. Thank you!

Comment: That's right. Just out of curiosity, did you use stars and bars to determine the $21$?

Comment: Hi Bob. Yes, I used 7C2 to obtain 21 ways to have a code adding up to 8. Then, 20P3/21P3 * 1/18 = 1/21, assuming we eliminate used codes.

Answer (score 5):

There are $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$ possible codes whose sum is $8$.

If the question is asking that you open it on exactly the fourth try, then you need three failures and one success.

$$\frac{20}{21} \cdot \frac{19}{20} \cdot \frac{18}{19} \cdot \frac{1}{18}=\frac{1}{21}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Is 6+5+4+3+2+1 number obtained as (1,1,6), (1,2,5), (1,3,4),... (1,6,1) then (2,1,5), (2,2,4)...(2,5,1) etc?

Comment: @user240383 Yes.  If the first disk is `1` there are 6 ways the remaining two sum to seven.  If the first disk is `2` there are 5 ways the remaining disks sum to six.  If the first disk is... and so forth.  It's a clear pattern.

Comment: @user240383 Yes, Graham Kemp explained my thought process. However, I think your stars and bars approach is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $x+y+z = 8, x,y,z \geq 1 \Rightarrow x'=x-1,y'=y-1,z'=z-1 \Rightarrow x'+1+y'+1+z'+1 = 8 \Rightarrow x'+y'+z' = 5, x',y',z' \geq 0$. There are $\binom{5+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{7}{2} = 21$ ways of turning the disks. And the probability of not getting it right is $\dfrac{20}{21}$ for each time. Thus to get the $4$ th right, we have the probability being: $\left(\dfrac{20}{21}\right)^3\cdot \dfrac{1}{21}$

Comment: Why would you not exclude a combination, that you have already tried?

Comment: I assume you don't remember (save) what you tried each time.

Comment: @NotALoner `you begin entering all codes whose sum is 8` That sounds like OP is trying to say you remember previous tries.

Comment: Theoretically, I don't think one is allowed to exclude what one already unsuccessfully tried. But I could be wrong...

Comment: Assuming you take steps to avoid trying the same pattern more than once (such as simply trying them in sequence `116`, `125`, `134`,...`611`), then the probability that you open the lock **on** the fourth try is indeed $1/21$.